# Renormalization Group Flows

Tags: renormalization, critical-phenomena

In the Renormalization Group flows, why there are two fixed points: Gaussian and Wilson Fisher and does the Gaussian Fixed point describe the critical behaviour of the system?

Comment: Hi! Please give more context to your question.
First question: without more context, there is no reason for having only 2 fixed points. Gaussian and Wilson-Fisher are just the names of two of them when they exist. The Gaussian fixed point is the trivial fixed point, and the Wilson Fisher fixed point is the non-trivial fixed point found in perturbation theory when working on the $\phi^4$ in dimension between 3 and 4 (https://www.lptmc.jussieu.fr/files/chap_rg.pdf).
Second question: No, because it's the non-interacting fixed point (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_fixed_point)